# How can I change the displayname of a VS Code extension after publishing it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can I change the displayname of 1 extension after publishing the extension?

I've tried modifying displayname directly in package.json, but it failed, and I wish there was a way to modify displayname.After I packaged with "vsce package", it seems that I didn't read the new displayname and description.

Answer (score 0):

When I finished modifying the displayname, I first tried it out through the vsix installation instead of releasing to the marketplace, and it didn't change the displayname at this point, after I released it, it changed!